# Terraform Azure VM doesn't recreate the instance even after changing custom_data

Tags: linux, bash, azure, terraform

I am trying to provision an an `azure` virtual machine and I need to install `kubectl` on it. So I am using a `bash` script and pass it to the VM's `custom_data` section.

Everything works fine - it provisions the VM and install the kubectl.

But the problem is, if I do some modifications to the the `bash` script, and do `terraform apply`, it show no changes as it doesn't detect that I did the changes to the `bash` script.

Here's my code snippet. Can someone help me understand this?

```
locals {
  admin_username = "myjumphost"
  admin_password = "mypassword!610542"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = var.vm_name
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = var.rg_name
  network_interface_ids = var.nic_id
  vm_size               = var.vm_size


  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = var.storage_image_reference.publisher
    offer     = var.storage_image_reference.offer
    sku       = var.storage_image_reference.sku
    version   = var.storage_image_reference.version
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = var.storage_os_disk.name
    caching           = var.storage_os_disk.caching
    create_option     = var.storage_os_disk.create_option
    managed_disk_type = var.storage_os_disk.managed_disk_type
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = var.vm_name
    admin_username = local.admin_username
    admin_password = local.admin_password
    custom_data    = file("${path.module}/${var.custom_data_script}")
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
    ssh_keys {
      key_data = file("${path.module}/${var.ssh_public_key}")
      path     = "/home/${local.admin_username}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    }
  }

  tags = merge(var.common_tags)
}
```

any my script `install.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# install Kubectl
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256"
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
kubectl version --client --output=yaml > /tmp/kubectl_version.yaml

# Install Azure CLI 
curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
```

Comment: Try using the refresh command; it has backward compatibility, but typically you won't need it because the plan will execute the same refresh. terraform apply -refresh-only -auto-approve.  It could be more informational, if any errors / screen shots on top.

Answer (score 0):

Try the refresh command; it was backwards compatible. Usually, it won't be necessary because the plan will execute the same refresh. Most confusion will be caused by bash or PowerShell scripts that are run as **cloud-init script on backed** and implement the functionality; we can cross-check that in activity logs.

```
terraform apply -refresh-only -auto-approve
```

I have tried to replicate the same with below mentioned code base

main tf file as follows

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-swarna-mindtree"
  location = "Germany West Central"
}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "puvnet" {
    name                = "Public_VNET"
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "Germany West Central"
  address_space       = ["10.19.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.19.0.4", "10.19.0.5"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "osubnet" {
  name                 = "Outer_Subnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.19.1.0/24"]
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.puvnet.name
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "testdemo"
  location                = "Germany West Central"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.osubnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
   name                  = "vmjumphost"
  location              = "Germany West Central"
  resource_group_name =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  //vm_size               = "Standard_A1_v2"
  vm_size ="Standard_DS2_v2"
   storage_image_reference {
    offer                 = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal"
    publisher             = "Canonical"
    sku                   = "20_04-lts-gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk2"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "vm-swarnademo"
     admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  //  custom_data    = file("${path.module}/${var.custom_data_script}")
    custom_data = file("install.sh")
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
    # ssh_keys {
    #   key_data = file("${path.module}/${var.ssh_public_key}")
    #   path     = "/home/${local.admin_username}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    # }
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

install sh file as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

# install Kubectl
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256"
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
kubectl version --client --output=yaml > /tmp/kubectl_version.yaml
#testing by adding command -start
#sudo apt-get -y update
#testing by adding command -End
#Install Azure CLI 
curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
```

Trying to update the script with below line of command

```
#testing by adding command -start
#sudo apt-get -y update
#testing by adding command -End
```

**Step1:**
while implement plan and apply, it was created all resources on portal.
[image]

[image]

**Step2:**
Updated the script by enable the code base

```
  #testing by adding command -start
    sudo apt-get -y update
    #testing by adding command -End
```

upon running plan and apply, it will refresh the state of the virtual machine and all the changes

[image]

**Verification from Activity Log:**
[image]